# Jquery remove parent or parents until a specific class name

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying to remove the main parent of a element like below, i want to remove the class named "well", but i cannot target it directly because its inside a PHP do while loop, so if i say `$('.well').remove()` all of the elements with a class name "well" will be removed.

```
<div class='well'>   
  <div class='container'>
     <div class='save-cl'>
         <button class='accept-call'> Accept</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

This is my jquery when i use parent the class `.save-cl` is being removed.

```
   $(document).on('click','.accept-call',function(){

           console.log("Accept was called");

             $(this).parent().remove();

});
```

When i use parents its removing all elements even the HTML so everything is white, is there a way to call `$(this).parents` but limiting it until a specific class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method to get the closest ancestor which matches the selector or element.

```
$(this).closest('.well').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

for class **removeClass()**  & for remove element Use remove()

```js
 

$(document).on('click','.accept-call',function(){

   console.log("Accept was called");
   $(this).parents(".container").parent().removeClass("well"); // for removeClass
 // $(this).parents(".container").parent().remove();  //for remove elelment

});
```

```css
.well{background:red;}
```

```html
   

 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class='well'>   
      <div class='container'>
         <div class='save-cl'>
             <button class='accept-call'> Accept</button>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code this

```
var cnt = $(".well").contents();
$(".well").replaceWith(cnt);
```

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery you can use  **.parents(selector)** to target the wanted (grand)parent.

```
$(document).on('click','.accept-call',function(){
    console.log("Accept was called");
    $(this).parents('.well').remove();
 });
```

It will not touch the other 'well' classes. If you want to remove the class not the whole div, then you can use **.removeClass('.well')** instead of **.remove()** .